# iTunes Connect-Transfer app between developer accounts

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app with all the app id, certificates, provisioning profiles and iTunes connect using an apple developer account. Status is prepare for submission.

Now I want to change the entire thing into another apple developer account. But, according to apple documentation, we have to have at least one version released into app store. But that is not true in my case.

So I would like to create app id, certificates, provisioning profiles and iTunes connect using new apple developer account and upload the build into iTunes using different bundle identifier but same build.

Is that possible to create different iTunes record with different bundle identifiers using different apple developer accounts for the same build?(Will iTunes check the ipa file if it already exists somewhere? I mean the source code is same in this case)

Do I have to change the app name to create new iTunes record or can I use the same app name?

Is there a better way to change the ownership instead of creating everything again?

Comment: Can you not add another Developer account to the profile (term probably incorrect)? Where I am working, we have 3-4 accounts registered under the same profile and can work freely with the same app.

Comment: You can probably upload the same app to the other account, but the many issue will be the app name as it already exists. (You should be able to fix the other issues with regards to identifiers etc.)